# Both XML and SQL as datasource in Crystal Report

Tags: sql, xml, crystal-reports, datasource

Is it possible to have multiple datasources in Crystal Reports?
As far as I have googled and searched on stackoverflow, its not possbile to have similar kind of datasource multiple times (they must have common end points).

But, now comes the questions, can we have one datasource as XML and other as SQL and query both at the same time?

Searched already but no link to confirm the same. Any link would be appreciated.

Comment: you mean you want the same data schema getting data from different source? example: one table (in crystal definition) filled with data from two different data sources

Comment: No, I mean both XML and SQL as datasource for a single report. Two table, one xml and one filled by sql stored proc.